# Parmi ou entre les années

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-temps, nombres

Quelle tournure est la plus adéquate (lors d'un exposé de candidature) ?

> Parmi les années académiques 2010-2015, j'étais...

ou

> Entre les années académiques 2010-2015, j'étais...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je dirais plutôt « durant », ou « au cours de » :

> Durant les années académiques 2010–2015, j'étais …
>   Au cours des années académiques 2010–2015, j'étais …

ou « entre », mais il faut formuler ainsi :

> Entre les années 2010 et 2015, j'étais …